# How to get actual width of UILabel text when set to word wrap

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have the following code to set up a UILabel:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.textAlignment = .center
label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = maxWidth

label.text = "String that is long enough to cause word wrap."

label.sizeToFit()
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

The result that I need is for the label to wrap the text as it would once it reaches `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth` then actually size itself to  just wide enough to fit the wrapped text.  Here's a diagram to illustrate:
[image]

The red box's width is equal to `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and that is the actual size I am getting with my code above.
The black box is the size that I would like it to be.
Whether the label was sized to the red or black, the word wrapping would be the same.

So, how can I resize my label to be the smallest possible width while maintaining the current word wrap?

**Edit:**

Although constraints might be the usual option, in my case, I don't think it is because I am sizing my superview according to the resulting size of this label.

Comment: Are you looking for [flush space](http://www.thedesigncubicle.com/2008/12/tiny-tutorial-improve-justified-type-settings/)? (See section *Adding Flush Space*)

Comment: Use `NSString boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` (or the Swift equivalent for `String`) to get the required size of the string.

Comment: @paulvs No, I don't think that's saying the same thing.

Comment: I usually solve this by adding leading and trailing constraints to my label so that it will wrap if it gets too long

Comment: @rmaddy I think you're on the right track.  I saw that too in obj-c threads, but was having a hard time finding the Swift equivilent for some reason.  I'm looking into it further.

Comment: @LulzCow Yes, I think that would be the typical way to handle it, but I failed to mention that this label is actually a subview of a UIPopover and I am setting the frame of the popover according to what the frame of the label ends up being. (Think tool tip)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I just figured it out. @rmaddy was correct in the question's comments above. I had seen `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` before asking the question, but had issues figuring it out in swift.  But now I've got it. Here is my updated code:

let label = UILabel()

```
    let text = "String that is long enough to cause word wrap."
    let rect = text.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: maxDesiredWidth, height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: nil, context: nil)

    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.frame = rect

    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    self.view.addSubview(label)
```